# Icon to represent component

Tags: icon, interface-design

I am building a drag and drop web builder.

One of the actions requires that the user select a *"component"* from the sidebar and drag it across the page. Once they drop it, the component fills the page.

Now, I do not want each component to have a unique icon... I would rather it be that I have one generic icon to represent a component.

Now my question is, what should that icon be? So far I am using a rounded square, which works ok... but seems kinda forced.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of looking for the *component* icon that is quite difficult to unify, you can do it by the element that unifies everything: the action → placing or putting.

[image]